# Wordpress sub-menu items suddenly not showing

Tags: menus, sub-menu

None of my submenus are showing. They all show up in Appearance->Menus, but not on the actual website. I've deactivated all of my plugins so it's not being caused by that. Help?

Website: http://www.barnhunt.co.uk/

What should be on the menu:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, Submenus are there.  There is theme css on line 77 of style.css hiding the submenu.

To explore, Use something like FireFoxs 'inspect element' and untick the display: none.  Take up with theme provider as to whether this is a bug (should show on hover), or intentional.

Also explore whether some plugin or other css is interfering.  You can do that by temporarily disabling everything else and using a clean browser (to avoid cache issues) to view the site.

[image]